# Renderizar imágenes dinámicamente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props, componentes

Estoy creando una aplicación React que muestre diferentes viajes realizados, para ello estoy renderizando los detalles de cada viaje junto con imágenes de cada lugar, a través de props, imágenes que tengo en una carpeta `images` en `src`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro que las imágenes se muestren para cada una de las instancias del componente que estoy renderizando del archivo local `data.js` donde tengo los datos que necesito mostrar.

Los demás datos que renderizo sí se muestran, solo me faltan las imágenes.

Quisiera saber que error estoy cometiendo. Adjunto el código.

```
import './App.css';
import Travel from "./components/Travel";
import data from "./data";

function App() {
  const travels = data.map(travel => {
    return ( <
      Travel key = {
        travel.id
      }
      image = {
        travel.imageUrl
      }
      location = {
        travel.location
      }
      url = {
        travel.googleMapsUrl
      }
      title = {
        travel.title
      }
      startDate = {
        travel.startDate
      }
      endDate = {
        travel.endDate
      }
      description = {
        travel.description
      }
      />
    )
  })

  return ( <
    div className = "App" > {
      travels
    } <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Aquí el archivo `data.js` donde se almacenan los datos de los travels

```
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Mount Fuji",
    location: "Japan",
    googleMapsUrl: "https://goo.gl/maps/1DGM5WrWnATgkSNB8",
    startDate: "12 Jan, 2021",
    endDate: "24 Jan, 2021",
    description: "Mount Fuji is the tallest mountain in Japan, standing at 3,776 meters (12,380 feets). Mount Fuji is the single most popular tourist site in Japan, for both Japanese and foreign tourists.",
    imageUrl: "mount_fuji.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Sydney Opera House",
    location: "Australia",
    googleMapsUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//-33.85691,151.215262/@-33.8567646,151.1452566,12z",
    startDate: "27 May, 2021",
    endDate: "8 Jun, 2021",
    description: "The Sydney Opera House is a multi-venue performing arts centre in Sydney. Located on the banks of the Sydney Harbour, it is often regarded as one of the 20th century's most famous and distinctive buildings.",
    imageUrl: "sydney_opera_house.jpeg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Geirangerfjord",
    location: "Norway",
    googleMapsUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//62.09137700000001,7.061933",
    startDate: "01 Oct, 2021",
    endDate: "18 Nov, 2021",
    description: "The Geiranger Fjord is a fjord in the Sunnmore region of More og Romsdal county, Norway. It is located entirely in the Stranda Municipality",
    imageUrl: "geirangerfjord.jpeg",
  }
]

export default data;
```

Aquí el componente Travel que debe renderizar los datos de los viajes
almacenados en data.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Travel(props) {
  
    return (
       <div>
            <img src= {`../images/${props.imageUrl}`} alt="landscape" />
            <div>
                <span>{props.location}</span>
                <span>{props.googleMapsUrl}</span>
                <h5>{props.title}</h5>
                <span><b>{props.startDate}</b><b>{props.endDate}</b></span>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Abre la consola de tu navegador y ve a la pestaña Network/Red si las imágenes no se muestran es probable que la ruta no sea correcta. Revisa si estás obteniendo algún tipo de error como 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @PabloLozano no, no estoy recibiendo ningún error en la consola del navegador, solo  una advertencia: URI no válida. Ha fallado la carga del recurso de medios .

Comment: @AndresGardiol en la pestaña Network/Red no estoy obteniendo ningún error 404 (Not Found), sin embargo sí estoy obteniendo un estado 304 (Not Modified), donde dice que el archivo es undefined

Comment: te recomiendo que agregues un [example]

Comment: @AndresGardiol abajo muestro una imagen donde se ve lo que digo, servirá ?

Comment: Por favor lee [example] ahi indica cómo agregar un ejemplo que nos permita reproducir el error y tratar de ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo está en el nombre de la propiedad: En el componente App defines lo siguiente:

```javascript
function App() {
  const travels = data.map(travel => {
    return ( <
      Travel key = {
        travel.id
      }
      image = { // <---- props.image
        travel.imageUrl
      }

      ...

      />
    )
  })
```

Pero luego en el componente Travel tienes `props.imageUrl`, que como no está definido es `undefined`.

```javascript
export default function Travel(props) {
  
    return (
       <div>
            <img src= {`../images/${props.imageUrl}`} alt="landscape" />
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Exactamente como usted dice Pablo, mi error estaba en que había colocado props.imageUrl en lugar de props.image en el componente Travel, ya lo he cambiado y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias !!